# Cannot print in VB2010 Windows Forms using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6

Tags: winforms, printing, vb.net-2010

I am trying to print from VB2010 Windows Forms using the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6` library.

I have downloaded the library and imported it onto my form. The Microsoft help files are inaccurate and incomplete, and there is not a complete example. A simple form with a print button that prints "Hello World!" to the default system printer would be enough to get me started.

Thanking you in advance for any help offered...

Answer (score 1):

Using the proper library will go a long end to making this simple.  Use the [PrintDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim doc = New PrintDocument()
        AddHandler doc.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintHello
        doc.Print()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintHello(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello world", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, New PointF(0, 0))
    End Sub
End Class
```